# Populate multiple fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, field, populate

I am new to javascript and I can't populate many fields with one click.

```
<script>
  function addTxt(txt, field)
  {
      var myTxt = txt;
      var id = field;
      document.getElementById(id).value = myTxt;
  }
</script>

<input type="text" name="xx" id="info" autofocus="required">
<p><a  href="#" onclick="addTxt('x', 'info')">x</a></p>
```

I've got 3 more fields.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're new, this is (sadly) going to get sorta complicated for you.  Make it easier on yourself and replace the `<a>` with a `<button>` or somethin

Comment: @Deryck How can I do it with a <button> ?

Comment: The element used will have no impact on this whatsoever.

Comment: Your current function can be simplified to `function addTxt(txt, id){ document.getElementById(id).value = txt; }`. There's no need to copy arguments to new local variables.

Comment: @BrunoGhisi just replace your `<a>` with `<button onclick="addTxt('x', 'info')" type="button">X</button>` and you can format it to look like anything in the world with CSS

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
function addTxt(txt, ids)
{
    for (var i=0, l=ids.length; i<l; ++i) {
        document.getElementById(ids[i]).value = txt;
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
addTxt('Some text', ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can populate multiple fields. I have shared a jsfiddle link. You can populate multiple fields using this code.

```
function addTxt(_val, _id,_no)
  {

  var _myTxt = _val;
  var _id = _id;
  for(var i=1;i<=_no;i++){
    document.getElementById(_id+i).value = _myTxt;
  }
```

}

[Click here to see DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z7rFU/)

Comment: Why do all variables begin with `_`?

Comment: I have updated my code on jsfiddle. Now you can populate multiple data using this code.Please check it out. [Click here DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z7rFU/1/)

Comment: We can you _ in variables or identifiers.

Comment: Its ok. Can you please increase my reputation or vote. So that i would be solving problems more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a function to do this.

Just use

```
document.getElementById('id1').value
    = document.getElementById('id2').value
    = document.getElementById('id3').value
    = 'Some text';
```

Or, if you think `document.getElementById` is too long, use a shortcut:

```
var get = document.getElementById;
/* ... */
get('id1').value = get('id2').value = get('id3').value = 'Some text';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the elements by tagName or by className instead of by id, then using a for loop to iterate through each one.